# Как правильно сделать конструктор в классе наследнике в С#?

Tags: c#

Допустим, есть два класса. Студент и аспирант. Как правильно сделать конструктор в классе-наследнике "Аспирант", чтобы инициализировались поля, которые есть в родительском классе и поля, которые есть в самом "аспиранте?"

```
class Student
    {
        protected string name;
        protected string faculty;
        protected string year;
        int rating;

        public Student(string name, string faculty, string year, int rating)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.faculty = faculty;
            this.year = year;
            this.rating = rating;
        }

    }

    class Aspirant :  Student
    {
        string teacher;
        string code;

        public Aspirant(string teacher, int code)
        { 

        }
    }
```

Comment: [`:base`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Comment: @Grundy, можно подробнее ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для вызова конструктора базового класса используется ключевое слово `base`:

```
class Aspirant :  Student
{
    string teacher;
    string code;

    public Aspirant(string teacher, int code) 
       : base(/*и тут передаются параметры конструктору базового класса*/)
    { 

    }
}
```

Вариант без `raiting`

```
class Student
{
    protected string name;
    protected string faculty;
    protected string year;
    int rating;

    //Конструктор по-умолчанию
    public Student ()
    {

    }

    //Конструктор, который не инициализирует raiting
    public Student(string name, string faculty, string year)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.faculty = faculty;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Student(string name, string faculty, string year, int rating)
        : this(name, faculty, year)
    {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

}


class Aspirant : Student
{
    string teacher;
    string code;

    public Aspirant(string teacher, string code)
    {
        //Здесь будет вызван конструктор по-умолчанию из Student
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Aspirant(string name, string faculty, string year, string teacher, string code)
       : base(name, faculty, year)
    {
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Comment: а если мне надо ,чтобы поле рейтинг не было у класса - наследника? То есть чтобы оно не инициализировалось?

Comment: @IWProgrammer, ну создайте конструктор, в котором не передается параметром `raiting` И что значит "небыло"?

Comment: но мне нужно в родительский класс передавать рейтинг, а класс - наследник нет. Как это реализовать? Тем более, что рейтинг ведь не наследуется, так как приватный по умолчанию

Comment: @IWProgrammer добавил как вариант

Comment: в данной строчке пишет ошибку недопустимого аргумента

this (!!!!string name!!!!, string faculty, string year)

Comment: @IWProgrammer поспешил. Уже исправил синтаксис

Comment: можете пояснить, а для чего нам пустой конструктор? Хотелось бы  до конца разобраться

Comment: и еще вопрос, что вообще происходит в строчках , подобной этой?

: this(name, faculty, year)

Comment: @IWProgrammer пустой, потому что из `public Aspirant(string teacher, string code)` т.к. мы ничего не вызываем должен вызваться базовый конструктор, а у вас его нет. Слово `this` в том контексте, означает вызов конструктора класса `Student` с теми параметрами, которые перечислены

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @IWProgrammer пожалуйста